# Need help converting nginx config to HAProxy

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I need to convert my NGINX Proxy to HAProxy.

Below is my nginx.conf, need help migrating to HAProxy

```
events {
}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        
        resolver 127.0.0.11 [::1];
        set $ws_port 9000;
        set $http_port 9000;

        # Go HTTP client is using that specific header
       
        
        if ($http_user_agent = "Go-http-client/1.1") {
            set $ws_port 8000;
        }

        if ($http_upgrade = "websocket") {
            set $upstream portainer1:$ws_port;
        }
        
        if ($http_upgrade = "") {
            set $upstream portainer1:$http_port;
        }
        
        proxy_pass http://$upstream;  

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

TIA

I'm a noob when it comes to HAProxy. Appreciate all the help.